# Access the result of $http.get in Angularjs outside function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

trying to create a Date object (using time only) and accessing that value outside of my function

Any help would be appreciated. See code below or my [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Nw8aCLLNDkskeB2oSeAI)

```
  var objts = "";

  $scope.today = function() {

        $http.get('time.json').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        objts   = new Date(data.time_start);
        objte   = new Date(data.time_end);

        console.log(data);
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("No data found..");
  });  

    $scope.dt = objts;  // ---- Trying to use value of objts here ----

  };
  $scope.today();
```

Thanks

Comment: you will only get async call response in their callbacks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `get` method is executed `asynchronously`. You are currently setting the `$scope.dt` value outside the `get` promise resolution function.

You should set the `$scope.dt` variable when the `get` promise resolve:

```
$scope.dt = null;

$scope.today = function() {
  $http.get('time.json').success(function(data) {
    var objts = new Date(data.time_start);
    var objte = new Date(data.time_end);
    $scope.dt = objts;
    console.log(data);
  }).error(function(data) {
    console.log("No data found..");
  });
};
$scope.today();
```

**Edit**
Your problem actually comes from the way you create your date. You should do something like:

```
$scope.dt = Date.parse("2016-01-01 " + data.time_start);
```

See the [Dates documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), or [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/), and [forked Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/jsKkZASlP97v2NNdcwPF?p=info)

Comment: Ok that makes sense, but I get the current time (not 08:00:00, the value in my json I want) when I do that. My plunker was updated to show what I mean

Comment: The problem lies in your date creation. You should do something like `Date.parse("2016-01-01 "+data.time_start);`